# Tag times protected; defining a function?

Tags: warning-messages

I know there are many questions similar to this, but I tried to follow the advice of the answers and it didn't seem to work. Maybe something else is at play here? Thank you.

```
Subscript[T, tr][x_, t_] := -(Pi/2)^2*Exp[-(Pi/2)^2*t]*Cos[(Pi/2)*x]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Quit the kernel and try again

Comment: Or perhaps `Clear[Subscript]`.